# How to catch selenium test exception?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm having a problem with Chrome - it often throws following exception

`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException.`

So I would like to catch all of them, not causing build to fails.

Comment: So I would like to catch all of them, not causing build to fails. - did not get this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a known issue -

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3000

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4319

Comment: Yes, it is. But I wonder is there a way to catch that exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the client to throw exception if failing status code occurred...

```
public class MyHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver {public class MyHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver {
    public MyHtmlUnitDriver(){
super();
this.getWebClient().getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);
}
```